# How to use a button in a VerticalFieldManager to change parent screen?

Tags: blackberry

I have a button in the a VerticalFieldManager. If a user clicks on it, I want to wipe out the screen and load up a new VerticalFieldManager.

Currently in the homepage, I call a custom manager that returns a VerticalFieldManager. Because the code that builds the VerticalFieldManager is not on the homepage and does not extend Mainscreen, it doesn't have access to the screen methods.

How can I go about fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly your screen has a manager and the manager has a button that you want to modify the screen.  You could do something like this:

```
ButtonField button = new ButtonField("Button");
button.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener(){
       public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context)
       {
            //The manager of this field should be the verticalFieldManager
            //and the manager of that should be the screen.
            Manager screen = field.getManager().getManager(); 
            screen.deleteAll();
            //Now create a new VerticalFieldManager and add whatever you want to it
       }

});
```